# Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE. dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a problem with the dialogflow and the diagnostic info that comes out :

```
{
  "responseId": "7cc5f6f7-c15c-43b4-99b8-3677b463d737-47692ce7",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "081908190819",
    "parameters": {
      "phone": 81908190819
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            ""
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/bookingteetime-lqsjjx/agent/intents/b967bab7-a6e1-499f-bbce-ba665b23c004",
      "displayName": "BookingConfirmation"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "diagnosticInfo": {
      "webhook_latency_ms": 3956
    },
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "webhookStatus": {
    "code": 14,
    "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: UNAVAILABLE."
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I spend so many times looking for a reasonable answer for this issue and finally I got a solution for it. In order to help futures sufferers I am posting what I founded out that solve my problem.

Change the version of your dialogflow-fullfilment from "0.5.0" para "0.6.1" This solved my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check your logs. Error Unavailable comes up whenever there is a problem in your fulfillment code. Use logs and try catch to figure out the issue.

Comment: This is true but perhaps unhelpful. JF may want to ask the original question poster for more detail since their question seems to be generically, "Help!", which is not specific enough to be answered well.

Comment: Agreed. Some more details of the code would help to diagnose better